# How to create a cron job for out of stock

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

How to create a cron job for out of stock that must daily run and check how many products are out of stock

Answer (score 0):

Create the file **`app/code/Custom/Module/etc/crontab.xml`** with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_module_out_of_stock_check" instance="Custom\Module\Cron\OutOfStockCheck" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

This configuration schedules the cron job to run every day at midnight (00:00).

Create the **`PHP class`** for the cron job.

Create the file **`app/code/Custom/Module/Cron/OutOfStockCheck.php`** with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Cron;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OutOfStockCheck
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $outOfStockProductsCount = $this->getOutOfStockProductsCount();
        $this->logger->info("Total out of stock products: " . $outOfStockProductsCount);
    }

    private function getOutOfStockProductsCount()
    {
        try {
            $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('quantity_and_stock_status', ['eq' => 0]);

            return $collection->getSize();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any queries.

**`Thanks`**